# an operator is it closed or bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I need help with the following problem:

Let $C^1[0,1]$ be the subspace of $C[0,1]$ that consists of continuously
differentiable functions on [0,1], and let $A$ be the operator defined by
$Af(x) = f'(x)$. Prove or disprove: (a) $A$ is closed; (b) $A$ is bounded.

p.s. the norm used is the max norm.

any help is greatly appreciated!!

thank you.

Comment: Which norm on $C^1[0,1]$ are you using?

Comment: that is the problem it does not say the norm, but can we work with the max norm.

Comment: $A$ is not bounded in $\Vert . \Vert_{\infty}$. Taking monomials $f(x)=x^n$

Comment: I updated the question, please see it again. thank you.

Comment: What's your definition of closed operator?

Comment: @masw980 by max norm you mean that $C^1$ is endowed with the usual $C^0$ norm? (this for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#Classical_spaces) or with ITS natural norm? (which is the sum of the max norm of the function and the max norm of its derivate?)

Answer (score 1):

$A : C^{1}[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ is bounded if you use the $C[0,1]$ on the range and the $C^{1}[0,1]$ norm on the domain because $\|f\|_{C^{1}[0,1]}=\|f\|_{C[0,1]}+\|f'\|_{C[0,1]}$ and $\|Af\|_{C[0,1]}=\|f'\|_{C[0,1]}\le \|f\|_{C^{1}[0,1]}$.

Comment: thanx, but I don't see why $\|f\|_{C^{1}[0,1]}=\|f\|_{C[0,1]}+\|f'\|_{C[0,1]}$